# Kotlin - What is the ` character for

Tags: syntax, kotlin, character

I have been using/learning Kotlin for a while now and I have only once seen **`** being used.

```
System. `in`
```

I have tried finding something about this, but I was not able to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s the **syntax for escaping keywords** like `in`. When a Java library uses one of these as an identifier (function/property name etc), it must be surrounded with *backticks* if called from Kotlin. Otherwise, the compiler tries to *interpret it as a keyword* which will make the code fail to compile.

> **[Escaping for Java identifiers that are keywords in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin)**
>
> Some of the Kotlin keywords are valid identifiers in Java: `in`, `object`, `is`, etc. If a Java library uses a Kotlin keyword for a method, you can still call the method escaping it with the backtick (`) character:
>
> ```
> foo.`is`(bar)
> ```

Here’s a list of keywords: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html

Comment: +1 - may be worth noting that it is not solely for escaping keywords, and there are still restrictions on identifiers surrounded with `, it is used to escape anything that would otherwise be an invalid identifier, such as anything starting with a digit or anything containing spaces - of course, these would not be accessible from Java code without causing a syntax error.